# Why is my function in a function being regarded as a pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am a bit familiar with pointers and function pointers, perhaps, but this is confusing. I have a function and here is its, function header;

`void report(List*, bool check(Item*, void*), void*);`

The actual function is implemented same as the prototype in the header file. The prototype in main is: `bool check(Item*, void*);`. Basically this just reports things from a list, based on the return value of `check`. When calling the function in `main.c`, I use      `report(list, check(item, specificArg), arg);` The only reason I am using void pointers, is because `arg`/`specificArg` could be whatever I want basically. But the problem is in `check(item, specificArg)`, where the compiler reports:

`incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'bool' to parameter of type 'bool (*)(Item *, void *)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing `check(item, specificArg)` you're actually calling the function and passing its return value to the call to `report`, while it expected a function pointer instead.

The correct call syntax is:
`report(list, check, arg);`

Comment: Well then if this is the case, how do I override my `specificArg` with an int, or a char, if `specificArg` is declared as void in the prototype?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to call `check` from within `report` passing `arg` as `specificArg`, right? If that's the case, you can call it as `check(item, arg)` from `report` and then do the converstion inside `check`.

Answer (score 0):

The function prototype

```
void report(List*, bool check(Item*, void*), void*);
```

takes 3 arguments,

1. A `List *` which is unnamed
2. A pointer to a function that takes an `Item *` and a `void *` and returns a bool -- this parameter is named `check`
3. A `void *` which is also unnamed.

You are calling it with `report(list, check(item, specificArg), arg)` Notice the second parameter you are passing is a `bool` --> the result of the call to `check(item, specificArg)`.  Thus the mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

this prototype is not correct:

```
void report(List*, bool check(Item*, void*), void*);
```

Suggest this prototype

```
void report( List*, bool, Item*, void*, void* );
```

then the signature would be:

```
void report( List* pMyList, Item* pmyItem, void* parm1, void* parm2 )
```

Then inside the report function:

```
bool mybool = check( pMyItem, parm1 );
```

However, if you want to pass different functions then suggest using the following prototype:

```
void report(List*, (bool (*)(Item*, void*)), void*);
```